# Passing an out clob procedure parameter as it is to a shell variable

Tags: shell, plsql, clob

I have a procedure that takes a clob as an out parameter.

I want to pass the clob content to the shell variable so that I can print it in a file, as it is in one line, but I got a different result : some blanks are deleted, and the result is printed in many lines!

This is the shell code :

```
#!/bin/bash
date_fich_ent=`date '+%Y%m%d'`;
heure_fich_ent=`date '+%H%M'`;
FILE_NAME="RIA_BMCE_TRX_${date_fich_ent}${heure_fich_ent}.TXT";

function_output=`sqlplus -s <<END
$1/$2@$3
set feedback off
set heading off
set pagesize 0
set serveroutput on 100000
DECLARE

  my_clob clob := null;

BEGIN
  proc_test('it',my_clob);
  dbms_output.put_line(my_clob);
  END;
  /
exit;
END`

echo "$function_output" > $FILE_NAME
```

Thanks.

Comment: any idea please?

Comment: Could you please give an example of data: how it looks after the output and how it should look?

Comment: It might look to you as one line in the IDE that you're using (Sql Developer etc.) or even in sqlplus, but it might be otherwise because of carriage returns for instance. Also, I think you should `set lines 1 set pages 1` in the script. Try it out.